# First weekday of the year (without weekends)

Tags: python

Can anyone help me get the first weekday (as a date) of a given year in Python?

This gives me the first Monday of the current week:

```
test = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=datetime.today().isoweekday() % 7)
print(test)
```

Comment: *"This gives me the first Monday of the current week"* - The ***first*** Monday of the week? When does a week have more than one Monday?

Comment: "First weekday" not counts *holidays*?  For example, 2023, first workday should be 01/03?   Because 01/02 is the *holiday*!  Prob. needs to be elaborate with a few examples...

Answer (score 0):

This is easy once you break it down:

Let's define a function that takes an input `yr` and returns the first weekday of that year.

```
def first_weekday(yr: int) -> datetime.date:
```

What is the first day of the year `yr`?

```
    first_day = datetime.date(yr, 1, 1)
```

Is that day a weekday? If so, it is the first weekday of the year.

```
    day_of_week = first_day.isoweekday()
    if day_of_week < 6: return first_day
```

[`datetime.date.isoweekday()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.isoweekday) returns `1` for Monday and `7` for Sunday.

<sup>Why did I use `isoweekday` instead of [`weekday`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.weekday)? No reason</sup>

If not, find how many days until Monday. Subtracting the `day_of_week` from `8` should do the trick!

<sup>We would subtract from `7` for `weekday()`.</sup>

```
    days_to_monday = 8 - day_of_week
    first_weekday = first_day + datetime.timedelta(days=days_to_monday)
    return first_weekday
```

Put this all together, and test:

```
for yr in range(2019, 2025):
    print(yr, first_weekday(yr))
```

prints:

```
2019    2019-01-01
2020    2020-01-01
2021    2021-01-01
2022    2022-01-03
2023    2023-01-02
2024    2024-01-01
```